# Seeming Contradiction With Complex Exponents

Tags: complex-analysis, exponentiation

I was fooling around while waiting for a page to load and came across the following "contradiction".

Let $x=(-1)^{i}$. Then $x^{i}=(-1)^{i\cdot i}=(-1)^{-1}=-1$. Thus, $x=\left(x^{i}\right)^{-i}=(-1)^{-i}=\left((-1)^{i}\right)^{-1}=x^{-1}$. Therefore, $x^2=1$, and so $(-1)^{i}=\pm 1$.

However, we can find a value of $(-1)^i$ that contradicts this. We have $-1=e^{i\pi}$ so that $(-1)^i=e^{-\pi}$, which is certainly not $\pm 1$.

Where is the mistake? I know the answer is absurd and I'm probably being terribly naive about exponents, but it seems solid.

Comment: I suppose that there may be several problems here, but the one I notice is that “$(-1)^i\,$” is not unambiguously definable. Any definition you give will involve $\log(-1)$, and there are infinitely many values of this, all equally unsatisfactory to your purpose.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that the rule $(a^z)^w=a^{zw}$ is ***not*** generally true for complex numbers.  As a simple example, using the principal branch for the complex logarithm we see that

$$(e^{i2\pi})^i=1^i=1\ne e^{-2\pi}=e^{i2\pi i}$$

> **In the OP, we see the incorrect expression**
>
> $$x=(x^i)^{-i} \tag 1$$

Note that $(1)$ is false since on the principal branch we have

$$\begin{align}
x&=(-1)^i\\\\
&=e^{i\log(-1)}\\\\
&=e^{i(i\pi)}\\\\
&=e^{-\pi }
\end{align}$$

and

$$\begin{align}
(x^i)^{-i}&=\left(-1\right)^{-i}\\\\
&=e^{-i\log(-1)}\\\\
&=e^{-i(i\pi)}\\\\
&=e^{\pi}\\\\
&=1/x\\\\
&\ne x
\end{align}$$